# Showing $f(x) = P(A \cap A_x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose that there are in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ independent events $A_1, A_2,...$ such that if $\alpha_n = \min \{ P(A_n), 1 - P(A_n) \}$ then $\sum_n \alpha_n = \infty$. Show that $P$ is nonatomic.

So far, I have shown that $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I am trying to work with the sets of the form 
$$
A_x = \{ \omega: \sum_n I_{A_n}(\omega) 2^{-n} \leq x \}
$$
and show that the function which maps to $P(B \cap A_x)$ is continuous in $x$ (where $B$ is any set in the $\sigma$ field). Then the fact that $P$ is nonatomic would follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

I am struggling to show that $P(B \cap A_x)$ is continuous in $x$. Intuitively, I think that it is connected to the fact that $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \rightarrow 0$, but I haven't been able to prove this.

Comment: What is $A_x$? $ $

Comment: @Did  Sorry I mistyped that, I fixed the question.

Comment: Now we only miss the meaning of $B$ -- and what you did to prove that $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Did $B$ is any set in the $\sigma$-field. To show that $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \rightarrow 0$, I just used the fact that the intersection of the sets is the product of the $\alpha_n$ (by independence), and that this goes to $0$ by the assumption that $\sum \alpha_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is not nonatomic, there is some singleton $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $P(\{\omega\}) > 0$.  Then $P(B_1 \cap \ldots \cap B_n) \ge P(\{\omega\})$ where
$B_k = A_k$ if $\omega \in A_k$, $A_k^c$ otherwise.

Comment: How do you know that if $P$ is nonatomic then there is some singleton $\omega$ such that $P(\{ \omega \}) > 0?$ How do you know that is not some other set of positive measure which has no subset of strictly smaller positive measure?

Comment: OK, an atom rather than a singleton.  Same principle: since $A_k$ is in $\mathcal F$, 
either it or its complement contains the atom.